# Disable multiple login codeigniter just once login

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to protect the login user so only 1 user can login on 1 browse or 1 device. I'm trying to create a ci_session and then how do I validate that a logged in user can't login in another medium with an active session or with session_id()?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a random code like FE454F34534

add a field in database and update this field on login  and set on session

every time user logins, check session code with database code